# Order of intersection between $A_7$ and $N_G(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have $G = S_7$ and $H = \langle (1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7) \rangle$, I'm finding the number of elements in $A_7\ \cap\ N_G(H)$.

I have $|N_G(H)| = 5040/120 = 42$ (120 is the number of conjugates of $H$ in $S_7$). And $A_7 = 2520$.

By the internal product formula, $|N_G(H) \ A_7| = \frac{35*2520}{|A_7\ \cap\ N_G(H)|}$, however I'm not sure how to go from there.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do any odd permutations normalize a $7$-cycle? ;-)

Comment: Yes there are, I don’t know how many though

Comment: Yes, so the intersection with $A_7$ is a proper subgroup and must be of index $2$ - half the elements of $N_{S_7}(H)$ are even, half are odd.

Answer (score 1):

The sign homomorphism $S_n\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ can be restricted to any subgroup $N\subseteq S_n$. The kernel of the homomorphism is $N\cap A_n$ which by Lagrange's theorem either has index $1$ or $2$ in $N$. Indeed $N\cap A_n$ has index one iff $N\subseteq A_n$ iff $N$ has no odd elements, which can be rephrased as saying $N\cap A_n$ has index two iff $N$ contains an odd element. Applying this to $N=N_G(H)$, since $N$ contains the odd element $(27)(36)(45)$ (which conjugates $(1234567)$ to its inverse), $N\cap A_7$ must have index two in $N$.

For completeness, we know $H$ has $120$ conjugates because there are $7!/7=6!$-many $7$-cycles and the map from $7$-cycles to cyclic subgroups they generate is a $6$-to-$1$ map (since $H$ has $6$ cyclic generators) which means the number of such subgroups is $6!/6=5!=120$. Then we know $|G|/|N_G(H)|=120$ by orbit-stabilizer, so $|N|=7!/5!$. Note this means $N\cong\mathbb{Z}_7\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_7^{\times}$.